# Show loader in Video Texture while video loading

Tags: three.js

I have used video texture `videoTexture = new THREE.VideoTexture(video);` to show video on canvas where video is html element. I want to show loader in video texture untill video gets loaded to play. Cuerently it's shows white screen and then playing video when video get loaded. Is there any way to achieve what i am looking?

Comment: What do you understand of a "loader". Would a static texture as a placeholder be okay? Or do you need an animated loader?

Comment: @Mugen87 any one from both will very helpful to me

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it like this: First, you apply a simple, static placeholder texture to your material that will later be used to display the video. Now it's important to replace this texture at the right time with the video (when the video is ready to play). You can try to use the `canplay` event in order to detect this situation. After you have obtained a reference to the video element, set the event listener like this:

```
const video = document.getElementById( 'video' );
video.addEventListener( 'canplay', changeTexture );
```

`three.js R91`